# Writing PDF anchor point into text element of layout using ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, pdf, arcgis-pro, layouts

I am currently working on an application that uses ReportLab to assemble PDF reports that include maps and tables (both created using ArcMap and ArcPy) and that application may soon be converted to use ArcGIS Pro and ArcPy instead.

As powerful as ReportLab is, much of the functionality *that we use* from it can be achieved using ArcGIS Pro and ArcPy, and it would simplify our deployment if ReportLab could be eliminated.

The requirement that I cannot meet without it is to embed a hyperlink in one single page PDF file that references an anchor point on another single page PDF file, and to have the hyperlink work when those two files are appended using `appendPages` on the [`PDFDocument` object](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/pdfdocumentcreate.htm) of ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro.

For the first step of this workflow, is it possible to write text into a Text element of one layout that can be used as an anchor point (e.g. Fig.1 is here) and have that anchor point remain usable when the layout is exported as a PDF file?

Changing the text in a text element is straightforward from ArcPy but it is the formatting to use within that text element which I seek, if it exists.

Comment: Have you seen https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234148/make-document-path-a-hyperlink-in-pdf ?

Comment: @Midavalo I'd not seen that Q&A (with an excellent answer from AlexTereshenkov) but it seems like it only links out from the final PDF rather than within the final PDF.  Nevertheless I'll continue to investigate it because it is certainly in the vicinity of what I am trying to do.